# random procedure wants exact integers in scheme

Tags: random, scheme, racket

I am given a real number which is between 0 and 1. This is my niceness-factor. This factor is a kind of probability. I mean if it is 0.2, it means that something will be happen with the probability of 1/5.

I tried to use

```
random
```

procedure for this. Here is my code piece:

```
  (if (eq? 'c (tit-for-tat my-history other-history))
   'c
   (if (= (random (/ 1 niceness-factor)) 0) 'c 'd))
```

However the "random" procedure wants me to give an exact integer number. How can I solve this problem? Is there any procedure similar to random?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your `niceness-factor` to an integer-like value (something comparable to the result of `random`).  For example:

```
(if (eq? 'c (tit-for-tat my-history other-history))
    'c
    (if (> (random 100) (* 100 niceness-factor)) 
        'c 
        'd)))
```

Comment: I would question the need to convert niceness-factor into an "integer like". You could simply do '(> (random) niceness-factor)' instead.

Comment: The Scheme `random` that I'm familiar with returns integers between 0 and `limit`.  Agreed, that some might return real numbers between 0 and 1.  `random` is not defined a part of any RnRS.

Comment: OP tagged with racket. The racket language defines both `(random limit)` returning an integer 0..limit. And `(random)` that returns an inexact number between 0 and 1 exclusive. See my answer for reference links. (IMO questions should not have both a racket tag and a scheme tag, unless one is using the R6RS or R5RS languages. The racket language evolved from scheme, but is not scheme.)

Comment: Also, the `>` should be either `<` or `<=`. Say `niceness-factor` is 0.2 as in OPs example. So you end up with `(if (> (random 100) 0.2))...)` Which has an 80% chance of being true, versus OP's trying to make a limit of 1/0.2 (5) and being true on only one `0` of the five possible values `0 1 2 3 4`. Not down voting yet, so you can correct, or point out the error in my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solving this, would be to use (random 1). Now if the result <= niceness-factor then do "something" else do "nothing".

Rationale:

There is 20% probability of obtaining a number <=0.2 in a range of (0,1) inclusive.

Comment: I didnt understand what do you mean.

Comment: @GoZoner basically created a code snippet based off of what I was saying. "something" was 'c and "nothing" was 'd going by your example. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

In the modules racket and racket/base `(random k)` generates an integer from 0 to k-1 inclusive. (k must be between  1 and 4294967087 inclusive) `(random` gives an inexact number between 0 and 1 exclusive. [reference guide: random provided by racket and racket/base](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=random#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._random%29%29)

Assuming you are using the racket, and not one of the other languages racket supports, from where you started adding a call to  [exact-round](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=floor#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/math..rkt%29._exact-round%29%29) would be closest to what you started with:

```
(if (eq? 'c (tit-for-tat my-history other-history))
    'c
    (if (= (random (exact-round (/ 1 niceness-factor))) 0) 'c 'd))
```

But I find the following to be simpler:

```
(if (eq? 'c (tit-for-tat my-history other-history))
    'c
    (if (<= (random) niceness-factor) 'c 'd))
```